# how the network card's MAC address is used for communication between devices?

Tags: networking, mac-address

Could you guys help me with that question in the title? I didn't find much useful and objective on the internet to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand OSI Model. Following is the answer specific to your question:

Layer 2 Communication Process:

- Machine A lookup’s for Machine D MAC address in its ARP table.
- If MAC Address found then packet is formed and sent to Switch A.
- If MAC address not found then ARP Request is generated and MAC address is
  obtained.
- Switch A receives packet and checks for MAC Address in its
  MAC Address Table.
- If MAC Address matched it will forward packet on
  matched port number.
- If MAC Address not found then the packet is
  broadcasted to all ports, except on which it has received the packet.
- Machine D receives packet from Switch A which was sent by Machine A.
- When Machine D will reply, same process will be followed as switching
  is done.

Source: https://community.cisco.com/t5/networking-documents/overview-of-layer-2-switched-networks-and-communication/ta-p/3128423

Comment: It's important to highlight that MAC adresses only matter at the local level (roughly when devices are on the same physical network medium or separated by only a switch). Routing over longer distances (between networks, such as over the internet) does not use the MAC adresses (well, individual steps within that routing do, of course, but your local PC doesn't need to know the MAC address of a server on the other end of the world and usually can't).